# Most important feature in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What is the most important or awaited feature in Visual Studio 2010??

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this but shouldn't this be a community wiki?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [Historical Debugger](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-28-An-Introduction-to-the-Historical-Debugger).   This records what happens during a run, and lets you step backwards and forwards through time in the debugger.

Comment: wow, that's pretty slick.  I had no idea they were adding this feature.

Comment: Wow, that's cool. I've been missing that for years (haven't had it since Quick C 2.5 on DOS...)

Comment: Your link had died; perhaps this would be a good replacement? http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/10-4/10-4-Episode-28-An-Introduction-to-the-Historical-Debugger

Answer (score 11):

As far as the IDE goes, proper, well-thought-out multi-monitor support is a big one..

Answer (score 8):

Support for parallel development.

Answer (score 6):

[It is running on top of WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2009/02/20/a-new-look-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx).

Comment: meh, that's more interesting than important.

Comment: It's important because Microsoft is dog feeding one of it's main product with the new technology (if you can say WPF is new).

Comment: then it's perspective-based. A dev who only does web won't care about it and may only see it as another reason why VS2010 _may_ be slow. A dev who writes WPF will benefit from a major deployment of WPF and the learnings Microsoft attains from the experience. Those learnings will shape WPF as it grows.  I see your point.

Comment: Running on WPF is also a reason why VS2010 *may* have better, less-buggy, plugins. I'm not worried about the perf, even with the hit from loading the managed dlls (that's only really start-up times). Also: http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2009/06/05/visual-studio-2010-performance-part-2-text-editor.aspx

Comment: I can tell you one place where this makes a difference.  I do a lot of development on a Virtual PC, and in VS 2008 there are weird graphical artifacts, so that a squiggly red line appears as a big ugly red smear.  In VS 2010, however, apparently due to the nature of WPF rendering, it appears as a squiggly red line just as it ought to.

Answer (score 5):

[F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233154(VS.100).aspx)  :)

Comment: Yes, none of the other features cannot compare with pushing such a language to mainstream by such a giant.

Comment: @Brian, I'm sure you're not biased at all. :)

Answer (score 4):

The new text editor written in WPF is very interesting. There is also a new extensibility framework that will make writing add-on for VS much easier (in my opinion the most important new feature). The tools for SharePoint development are nice additions. There is a new debugger that records the debugging process and has greater support for parallel programming.

Answer (score 2):

Usable SharePoint integration...bring it on!

Comment: that's not really the same thing though is it...
A 'Wiki' is not really anything in and of itself.

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic language runtime will lead to much more readable code when dealing with COM application and will be interesting to see where it takes staticaly typed languages.

Answer (score 0):

Afair, they promised to include WiX 3.0. Although not perfect tool (built on top of ugly MSI plus some xml hell) but we don't have alternatives (at least from Microsoft), do we (tried their Setup projects)?

Answer (score 0):

Architectural View(Designer) of the Application
This enables the new developers to understand the application flow more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Improvment of the TDD Good Channel 9 example. It way simpler now with an awesome intelli-sense.